# Heroku not loading ajax calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

I have a feature that lets users add courses to their shopping cart. Everything works fine in development: when a user clicks on the "add to cart" icon, it creates a line_item object in the cart, and the carts_controller executes an AJAX request that loads the updated html for the cart. Here's the code:

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @cart = @user.cart
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(params[:line_item]) 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Course added to cart') }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item, :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
```

The format.js then references the create.js.erb file:

```
$("#cart").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)) %>");
```

This pulls in the @cart partial, which contains the newly inserted line_item.

When I uploaded this to heroku, however, this part of my code broke. When I click on the "add to cart" icon, the line_item is created, but the page has to refresh before it shows the cart.

Is there something I have to do within heroku before it recognizes this kind of AJAX call?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't need anything specific for ur AJAX to work on Heroku.Just make sure you properly include prototype.js in your file OR prototype.js is present in the ur application folder

Answer (score 1):

for me, the solution was to change:

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

(was 'false')

Answer (score 0):

You might need to pre-compile your assets.

run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally. This will create a assests folder in the public directory. add all of them and commit that to heroku.